# Xcode Forward declaration in header or Declared only in implementation file

Tags: objective-c, import, header, forward-declaration

Why should we use forward declaration, if the class only imported in implementation file?

For example, in ViewController.h

```
@class AnObject

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

in ViewController.m

```
#import AnObject.h

@interface ViewController (){
    AnObject *anObject;
}
@end
```

Edited: Can we just remove @class AnObject in header file based on the example?

Comment: There is no reason at all for the `@class AnObject` in that .h since the .h doesn't reference the class.

Answer (score 1):

Forward declaration is used to minimize dependencies between classes. Imagine if you have a very large project the imports would grow and grow adding unnecessary compilation to your code. Using forward declaration in your headers significantly decreases compilation time. Although, the new compilers are so advanced that forward declaring classes is probably unnecessary. Consider that C & C++ were standardized at a time when every CPU cycle really counted do to speed and such and system memory was minimal. Now I basically use the `@class` directive to keep my code cleaner and more uniform.

Comment: What I mean is , can we just remove @class AnObject in header file (.h) and let the class imported in implementation file?

Comment: No, how else would the compiler know about the classes being used in the header file? You need to use `@class` or `#import` your class headers into the header file.

Comment: I didn't declared any class in header file, but declared in class extension .m instead.